# android Unknown chromium error: -6

Tags: android, html, cordova

I was debugging my phonegap android application and I saw `Unknown chromium error: -6` on logcat console.

```
Level = D
Tag = chromium 
Text = Unknown chromium error: -6
```

Can someone please explain what this error means.

Answer (score 5):

In most of the cases, this error is due to the files,

- The files probably are not dynamically loading correctly (no permission, looking in the wrong place).
- The `URl` you have provided may be wrong.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow get more information about the specific file/url that Chromium is trying to load?

Comment: I had this error show up when the page I was loading attempted to use a javascript file that wasn't in the project's "assets" folder